# Tomcat server.xml connection timeout configuration

Tags: tomcat, webserver

I have read that connection timeout in *server.xml* just close connection in case of timeout but it would not stop thread which is going processing for request. In that case what we are achieving by closing connection?

I am not sure how much resources are occupied by a connection, I thought closing connection will just release socket (some memory). I just want to understand real advantage of this flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Apache Tomcat `connectionTimout` is described in the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) as

> The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait, after accepting a
>   connection, for the request URI line to be presented. The default
>   value is 60000 (i.e. 60 seconds).

It defines the amount of time the connection is held open. As for the question of why close connections, again from [Apache documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/timeouts.html),

> Setting communication timeouts is very important to improve the communication process. They help to detect problems and stabilise a distributed system.

In short, you are achieving stability and effective error logging by making sure your connection pool is clean.